# Changes in captcha image through coding

Tags: php, captcha

I use the following captcha code which works correctly:

```
<?php
session_start();
//You can customize your captcha settings here

$captcha_code = '';
$captcha_image_height = 50;
$captcha_image_width = 130;
$total_characters_on_image = 6;

//The characters that can be used in the CAPTCHA code.
//avoid all confusing characters and numbers (For example: l, 1 and i)
$possible_captcha_letters = 'bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz23456789';
$captcha_font = './monofont.ttf';

$random_captcha_dots = 45;
$random_captcha_lines = 20;
$captcha_text_color = "0x021f64";
$captcha_noise_color = "0x021f64";


$count = 0;
while ($count < $total_characters_on_image) { 
$captcha_code .= substr(
    $possible_captcha_letters,
    mt_rand(0, strlen($possible_captcha_letters)-1),
    1);
$count++;
}

$captcha_font_size = $captcha_image_height * 0.65;
$captcha_image = @imagecreate(
    $captcha_image_width,
    $captcha_image_height
    );

/* setting the background, text and noise colours here */
$background_color = imagecolorallocate(
    $captcha_image,
    255,
    255,
    255
    );

$array_text_color = hextorgb($captcha_text_color);
$captcha_text_color = imagecolorallocate(
    $captcha_image,
    $array_text_color['red'],
    $array_text_color['green'],
    $array_text_color['blue']
    );

$array_noise_color = hextorgb($captcha_noise_color);
$image_noise_color = imagecolorallocate(
    $captcha_image,
    $array_noise_color['red'],
    $array_noise_color['green'],
    $array_noise_color['blue']
    );

/* Generate random dots in background of the captcha image */
for( $count=0; $count<$random_captcha_dots; $count++ ) {
imagefilledellipse(
    $captcha_image,
    mt_rand(0,$captcha_image_width),
    mt_rand(0,$captcha_image_height),
    2,
    3,
    $image_noise_color
    );
}

/* Generate random lines in background of the captcha image */
for( $count=0; $count<$random_captcha_lines; $count++ ) {
imageline(
    $captcha_image,
    mt_rand(0,$captcha_image_width),
    mt_rand(0,$captcha_image_height),
    mt_rand(0,$captcha_image_width),
    mt_rand(0,$captcha_image_height),
    $image_noise_color
    );
}

/* Create a text box and add 6 captcha letters code in it */
$text_box = imagettfbbox(
    $captcha_font_size,
    0,
    $captcha_font,
    $captcha_code
    ); 
$x = ($captcha_image_width - $text_box[4])/2;
$y = ($captcha_image_height - $text_box[5])/2;
imagettftext(
    $captcha_image,
    $captcha_font_size,
    0,
    $x,
    $y,
    $captcha_text_color,
    $captcha_font,
    $captcha_code
    );

/* Show captcha image in the html page */
// defining the image type to be shown in browser widow
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); 
imagejpeg($captcha_image); //showing the image
imagedestroy($captcha_image); //destroying the image instance
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $captcha_code;

function hextorgb ($hexstring){
  $integar = hexdec($hexstring);
  return array("red" => 0xFF & ($integar >> 0x10),
               "green" => 0xFF & ($integar >> 0x8),
               "blue" => 0xFF & $integar);
               }
?>
```

Result of above code:
[Generated captcha image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuOyh.png)

As you can see in the image, the generated image for captcha has only one color, which is very annoying.

I want each part of the generated captcha image to have different colors so that it looks beautiful in addition to making it harder for robots to guess it.

What I'm looking for is to generate the captcha image as follows:
[My desired captcha image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOQGu.png)

Is there a need for a separate library to generate such a captcha image or can it be implemented with a few changes in the code?

Comment: No, that should not need a different image library. The `imagettftext` call currently writes all six characters in one go - so you would have to split that part up, so that each letter gets put onto the image separately, using a different color. And in the loops that generate the random dots and random lines, those are generated one by one already, so there you would just have to switch the color between iterations then.

Comment: As you can see in the picture, the lines in the picture have different colors and I want to recreate the exact same picture. Please, if possible, edit my code to produce the exact image I want.

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service. I gave you some hints already, so now is the time for you to make an attempt. _"As you can see in the picture, the lines in the picture have different colors"_ - already addressed that in my first comment. All those lines get put onto the image one by one, so all you need to do is supply a different color each time within that loop. So either fill an array with `$random_captcha_lines` number of different color values, and pick one via the loop index; or use less colors (if repetition is okay), and use loop index modulo number of colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a separate library for this, but you need to update the way you allocate colors and draw elements on the image.

- Modify the colors for text, dots, and lines to be random for each
  element.
- Update the code for drawing the captcha text, dots, and
  lines with random colors.
- Adjust the color allocation within the
  loops for dots and lines to ensure random colors are generated.

You can try following code::

```
<?php
session_start();

// You can customize your captcha settings here
$captcha_code = '';
$captcha_image_height = 50;
$captcha_image_width = 130;
$total_characters_on_image = 6;

// The characters that can be used in the CAPTCHA code.
// Avoid all confusing characters and numbers (For example: l, 1, and i)
$possible_captcha_letters = 'bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz23456789';
$captcha_font = './monofont.ttf';

$random_captcha_dots = 45;
$random_captcha_lines = 20;

$count = 0;
while ($count < $total_characters_on_image) { 
    $captcha_code .= substr(
        $possible_captcha_letters,
        mt_rand(0, strlen($possible_captcha_letters)-1),
        1
    );
    $count++;
}

$captcha_font_size = $captcha_image_height * 0.65;
$captcha_image = @imagecreate(
    $captcha_image_width,
    $captcha_image_height
);

/* Generate random dots and lines in the background of the captcha image */
for ($count = 0; $count < $random_captcha_dots; $count++) {
    $image_noise_color = imagecolorallocate(
        $captcha_image,
        mt_rand(0, 255),
        mt_rand(0, 255),
        mt_rand(0, 255)
    );

    imagefilledellipse(
        $captcha_image,
        mt_rand(0, $captcha_image_width),
        mt_rand(0, $captcha_image_height),
        2,
        3,
        $image_noise_color
    );
}

for ($count = 0; $count < $random_captcha_lines; $count++) {
    $image_noise_color = imagecolorallocate(
        $captcha_image,
        mt_rand(0, 255),
        mt_rand(0, 255),
        mt_rand(0, 255)
    );

    imageline(
        $captcha_image,
        mt_rand(0, $captcha_image_width),
        mt_rand(0, $captcha_image_height),
        mt_rand(0, $captcha_image_width),
        mt_rand(0, $captcha_image_height),
        $image_noise_color
    );
}

/* Create a text box and add 6 captcha letters code in it */
$text_box = imagettfbbox(
    $captcha_font_size,
    0,
    $captcha_font,
    $captcha_code
); 
$x = ($captcha_image_width - $text_box[4]) / 2;
$y = ($captcha_image_height - $text_box[5]) / 2;

/* Show captcha image in the HTML page */
// Defining the image type to be shown in the browser window
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Loop through each character and assign a random color
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($captcha_code); $i++) {
    $character_color = imagecolorallocate(
        $captcha_image,
        mt_rand(0, 255),
        mt_rand(0, 255),
        mt_rand(0, 255)
    );

    imagettftext(
        $captcha_image,
        $captcha_font_size,
        0,
        $x + $i * $captcha_font_size * 0.7, // Adjust character spacing
        $y,
        $character_color, // Use the randomly allocated color
        $captcha_font,
        $captcha_code[$i] // Render each character individually
    );
}

imagedestroy($captcha_image); // Destroying the image instance
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $captcha_code;

?>
```

Comment: Your code is great and solved my problem well. Is there just a way to make the generated characters each have a different color? (like the picture I put in my question)

Comment: I have edited my answer. you can try that, @Program

Comment: Hello. I apologize for the late reply. Your answer is excellent and the only problem is that the captcha image is not displayed, which was solved by placing this code at the bottom of the page: `imagejpeg($captcha_image);` Thank you very much for your reply.